# How to find attribute values of components in an HTML page other than inspecting it

Tags: html, testing, extjs, html-components

I've been working on Sencha test and I am in a situation to find all the attribute values like IDs, NAMEs, etc to add those in my scripts, to represent the component. So what I am doing for that is, 
**go to web page -> right click component -> Inspect element -> and then get enough component attributes** by referring to the HTML code.
**Is there any way to find attribute values of components in an HTML page other than inspecting it ???** **Please advice..**

Comment: Is there any specific xtype to that component? i mean which field or component?

Comment: Not any specific type. I want to get attribute values of Any type components like textfields, combobox, radio buttons, checkbox, buttons, etc.

Comment: *I've been working on Sencha test* - Sencha Test (or) Sencha Touch?

Comment: its unclear what exactly you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the **App Inspector for Sencha** chrome extension, which will help you to debug ExtJS and Sencha Touch applications much easier.

It also helps you to inspect your component tree, data stores, events, and layouts.

You can install it from the below URL,

[App Inspector For Sencha](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-inspector-for-sencha/pbeapidedgdpniokbedbfbaacglkceae?hl=en)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To get Attribute Values of component elements programmatically:

First, get the component. There are various ways, e.g.:

- `var component = Ext.getCmp(id)` gets you the component with a certain id.
- `var component = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(xtype)` gets you an array of all components of a certain `xtype`

Second, on that component, call `getEl()` or any other element selector, e.g.:

- `var el = component.getEl()`
- `var el = grid.getView().getEl()`
- `var el = formfield.inputEl`

Third, on the el, call `getAttributes`:

`var attributes = el.getAttributes()`

attributes will now contain an object like this:

```
class:"x-grid-view x-grid-with-col-lines x-grid-with-row-lines x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable"
data-componentid:"tableview-1325"
id:"tableview-1325"
role:"rowgroup"
style:"margin: 0px; overflow: auto; width: 317px; height: 664px;"
tabindex:"0"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can press ctrl+u that will show you the page source. use ctrl+f to find the element which u want. This is easier than inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the browser console and execute the below script to collect the list of attributes of each element.

```js
var parentEl = document.getElementById("container");
getElementsAndAttributes(parentEl);

function getElementsAndAttributes(container) {
  var all = container.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
    console.log(all[i].tagName);
    var attrs = all[i].attributes;
    var keys = Object.keys(attrs);
    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
      var attr = attrs[keys[j]];
      console.log(attr.name + " -> " + attr.value);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <span class="title" style="color:GREEN;">Phineas</span>
    <img src="https://cdn.pastemagazine.com/www/blogs/lists/2010/05/12/phineas.jpg" width="104" height="142">
  </div>
</body>
```